# Google Drive deletes files while syncing

Tags: google-drive, online-storage

I just made the switch from Dropbox to Drive and had to upload ~60GB of files. About 15% in, the Google Drive app on my Mac slowed down and I restarted it. But instead of continuing with the upload, it deleted some of my files one-by-one (and put it in my trash).

The files that got deleted were already uploaded to Google Drive, so it makes no sense to me that they got deleted. Any clues or pointers? Can I reset the "file catalogue" somehow? I haven't started Google Drive since, because I'm worried about another loss of files.

Local files should have always priority in my case, Drive is mainly used for online backup and occasionally sharing.

Comment: Since you're asking about the file synchronization function of Google Drive, rather than the web interface, your question is off-topic here. It should be on-topic at [su]. Read the [tag description](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/google-drive/info) for more information.

Comment: In my experience many other services are really not as robust as Dropbox and Google Drive especially frequently induces some sort of issue, especially when you're transferring the files for the first time. The recovery of lost files is also incredibly tedious. I once had an issue between OneDrive and Sugarsync if I recall correctly. I think it has something to do with timestamping. In any case, make sure you still have a backup of the files somewhere (e.g. back in Dropbox or copied in another place on hard drive) before the whole uploading is complete. This process is very dangerous.

Comment: Also make sure no two syncing apps are running at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it by deleting the `Drive` folder inside `~/Library/Application Support/Google`. Then I reopened the Drive app and it starts with a new file catalogue. I had to do this several times before everything was uploaded because the Drive app kept crashing.

Lesson learned: Back up everything before moving your cloud.